# Multiple HTTPS endpoints for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, https, endpoint

I have a WCF service that works with two endpoints: HTTP and https.
I need to add another https endpoint so that one would require Client certificate and another one wouldn't.

If I add new https endpoint with its own base address I get the error:

> System.ArgumentException: This collection already contains an address with scheme https.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.

I tried adding

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

but it didn't help - getting the same error.

If I add new https endpoint using the same Listen Uri but different binding configuration then I get the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'https://localhost:9907/myservice/myservice'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance.

But I need two different bindings - one with Client certificate requirement and one without.

Is it feasible?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how you could support multiple bindings on the same URL. How would the client and server know which handshaking to use? You'll have to vary the URLs (slightly) and have two endpoint definitions.

Comment: I thought I could use two different URLs but it seems it won't let me having two https URLs for the same service

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. 
The two https endpoints must use the same binding TYPE not the same binding configurations, and also have different names like so:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" />
    <binding name="HTTPSNoCert">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="HTTPSWithCert">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="b1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
      name="BhttpEP" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="bs1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HTTPSNoCert"
      name="bHttpsEP1" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="bs2" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HTTPSWithCert"
      name="bHttpsEP2" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://myhostname:7654/b1" />
        <add baseAddress="https://myhostname:7655/b2" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: I spoke too soon. The service starts but calling a method using https fails with Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.